# Installing Debian package tools (dpkg-buildpackage) on Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dpkg, amazon-linux, deb

I am setting up a web server which packages and hosts different installers for client applications on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.

I am using EC2 so I went with Amazon Linux for my base image.

I have the repackaging working fine for creating Windows, Mac OS X, and RPM-based installers, however I can't find `dpkg-buildpackage` anywhere in the Amazon Linux package repositories, so I currently can't create installers for our Debian and Ubuntu-based clients.

I tried searching for the `dpkg-buildpackage` source, but it's a fraught search term: all I found were people asking questions about using `dpkg-buildpackage` to build things from source, but not the source of the build tool itself.

How can I install `dpkg-buildpackage` on Amazon Linux so I can create `.deb` installers?

Comment: Start over with CentOS. Amazon Linux is not worth using, for this and many other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to install it.

**Steps:**

```
# install ncurses-devel prereq
yum install ncurses-devel
wget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.10.tar.xz
tar xvf dpkg_1.18.10.tar.xz
cd dpkg-1.18.10
./configure
make
make install
```

After installing it, I noticed that running `dpkg-buildpackage` was failing due to missing the `Dpkg.pm` perl module, so I installed that:

```
yum install cpan
cpan install Dpkg
```

Then the `@INC` path didn't have the newly installed module's path, so I modified the global profile to include it:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/perl5lib.sh
# perl5lib initialization

export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/usr/local/share/perl5/vendor_perl
```

and everything seemed to work.